# Formit problems - letters not sent

Tags: php, email, modx, modx-revolution, formit

Formit extra sends letters in my demo site but when I try to use it on my clients' server, letters are not going anywhere. However, the success message comes correctly. Clients' server is **https://** .

My formit code is:

```
[[!FormIt?
&hooks=`spam,email,FormItSaveForm,FormItAutoResponder`
&validate=`name:required,email:required`
&successMessage=`Thanks for contacting Us!. We will get in touch with you shortly.<br/>`
&emailTo=`name@mydomain.in`
&emailTpl=`sendEmailTpl`
&emailSubject=`Careers Submission`
&fiarTpl=`autoEmailrespondCareer`
&fiarSubject=`Solutions`
&fiarReplyTo=`name@mydomain.in`
&fiarFrom=`name@mydomain.in`
&formName=`Careers`
&fieldNames=`name==Name,desig==Designation,current_cpname==Current Company,country==Country,phone==Phone,email==Email,yrexp==Years of Experience,filecareer==Uploaded CV,comment==Comments`
&formFields=`name,desig,current_cpname,country,phone,email,yrexp,filecareer,comment`

]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `QuickEmail` extra and check your client server:

```
[[!QuickEmail?
    &to=`my-mail@mydomain.ru`
    &debug=`1`
]]
```

Comment: OK Vasis . Thnx for fast reply